# Erro wordpress na instalação do tema

Tags: wordpress

Quando importo o conteúdo de um tema no wordpress, retorna esse mensagem de erro

**Invalid post type services**

Como faço para resolver isso para que consiga instalar o conteúdo do tema corretamente?

Comment: Em que parte da instalação da o erro?

Comment: eu instalo o wordpress importer, e quando vou importar o arquivo .xml no final retorna esse erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difícil saber exatamente o que acontece, mas acredito que seu blog antigo tenha um custom post type definido diretamente pelo tema, e o atual não, onde dá problema na importação por não encontrar esse CPT ativo, tente verificar em qual parte do template antigo há esse codigo e insira no function.php do template atual, ou melhor ainda, você pode usar um plugin que crie custom post types e utilizar dos mesmos parâmetros do que estava no template antigo.